# Making an active link in PHP

Tags: php

I've created a blog site with php. There's a section where you can make a comment. I was wondering how I could make the url active when someone post one in a comment. I've noticed that when I make a comment with a url in it, the link is not active or you can't hover over it. Is there a code to make it active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the part of the string which is a URL to a link.

```
// The Regular Expression filter
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

// The Text you want to filter for urls
$text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";

// Check if there is a url in the text
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) 
{
    // make the urls hyper links
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);
} else {
    // if no urls in the text just return the text
    echo $text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: A positive feedback will be nice :)

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow in the morning. What will be the value of the variable $url? Just curious. Just in case I get an error.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Is there another area where I could leave positive feedback?

Answer (score 0):

for comment sections instead of using textarea use text editors.There so many open source text editor are in market. like

```
http://nicedit.com/===================this one very beautiful 
http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/
http://jqueryte.com/ 
http://ckeditor.com/
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a text editor for the admin section. Never thought to add it to the comment section. Thanks.